# Debian: Find binary and debug files by build-id

Tags: debian, debugging, core-dump

Assuming I have a core dump from a Debian system, where I know the build-ids of the libraries used in the dump, but don't know the exact versions, is there a way to find those files?

For example, the command `eu-unstrip -n --core my-core-file` gives me a list of build-ids from a core dump, like this:

> 0x7f09b7228000+0x272108 **1b72306ef00166fe1511d57140b50f5ce341170e**@0x7f09b72281d8 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 - **libpcre.so.3**
>
> 0x7f09bac07000+0x219208 **908b5a955d0a73fb8d31e0f927d0cdba810cb300**@0x7f09bac071d8 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 - **libz.so.1**
>
> 0x7f09bb06c000+0x20fd88 **06ea95ca3df11e4a8e85791c1ff89a49fc3fe9c1**@0x7f09bb06c1d8 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 - **libbz2.so.1.0**

Based on these library names and build-ids, is there a command, web service or anything that can tell me which package or file versions these build-ids correspond to, so that I can download them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I’m aware there’s no *tool* to search for build-ids (but see further down).

You can use `apt-file` to search for packages providing the libraries in use. Install it, update the indexes, then run

```
apt-file search /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3
apt-file search /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
apt-file search /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0
```

To use build-ids, you’ll need to look through `Packages` files manually. The index for debug repositories includes the build-ids; for example

```
$ apt show libbz2-1.0-dbgsym
Package: libbz2-1.0-dbgsym
Version: 1.0.6-8.1
Auto-Built-Package: debug-symbols
Priority: extra
Section: debug
Source: bzip2
Maintainer: Anibal Monsalve Salazar <anibal@debian.org>
Installed-Size: 68.6 kB
Depends: libbz2-1.0 (= 1.0.6-8.1)
Homepage: http://www.bzip.org/
Build-Ids: 06ea95ca3df11e4a8e85791c1ff89a49fc3fe9c1
Download-Size: 51.5 kB
APT-Sources: http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug stretch-debug/main amd64 Packages
Description: Debug symbols for libbz2-1.0
```

To search for the build-ids directly, `grep` through `/var/lib/apt/*Packages`:

```
grep -l 06ea95ca3df11e4a8e85791c1ff89a49fc3fe9c1 /var/lib/apt/lists/*Packages
```

You can combine this with `less` to see the name and version of the package:

```
grep -l 06ea95ca3df11e4a8e85791c1ff89a49fc3fe9c1 /var/lib/apt/lists/*Packages | xargs -r less -p06ea95ca3df11e4a8e85791c1ff89a49fc3fe9c1
```

This will only work if you have the indexes for debug packages; to get those, add a file to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, call it for example `debug.sources`, containing

```
Types: deb
URIs: http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/
Suites: stretch-debug testing-debug unstable-debug experimental-debug
Components: main
```

This will download the debug indexes for the main component in stable, testing, unstable and experimental.

Some packages (such as `libpcre3`) don’t build `-dbgsym` packages, so they’re not covered by the search above. There’s a corresponding `libpcre3-dbg` but as far as I can tell none of the versions currently in the archives match your build-id.